# Blob doesn't work in Intel xdk android build

Tags: android, blob, hybrid-mobile-app, intel-xdk

Could anyone explain why Blob constructor raises an error in intel xdk android build?

```
var values = [];
var urlArray = [];
var blob;
try{
   blob = new Blob([values, urlArray]);
} 
catch(e) {
   alert(e);  //TypeError: Illegal constructor
}
```

Alert's output is:-

```
TypeError: Illegal constructor
```

The same code works well in debug preview of intel xdk. How come? 
How to make it work in android build?

Answer (score 0):

This is an Android WebView issue. Constructing blobs (binary large objects) are **only supported in Android version 3.0 and above** since WebKit is now used as the basis for rending web content in the browser and WebView.